# Why my delete button didn't delete all widgets on QHBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem when deleting my widgets on QHBoxLayout.
i use QList for listing my layout, because i add layout at runtime.
this is my QList

```
QList<QHBoxLayout*> hBoxLayoutParent;
```

this my code when i add my widgets

```
hBoxLayoutParent.push_back(createNewHBoxParent());
hBoxLayoutParent.last()->addWidget(label);
hBoxLayoutParent.last()->addWidget(cmbBox);
hBoxLayoutParent.last()->addWidget(cmbJurusan);
hBoxLayoutParent.last()->addWidget(listButton.last());
ui->formLayout_2->addLayout(hBoxLayoutParent.last());
```

and this how i delete them

```
for(int i = 0; i < hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count(); i++)
{
    delete hBoxLayoutParent[index]->takeAt(0)->widget();
    qDebug() << "Widget Number: " << hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count();
}
hBoxLayoutParent.removeAt(index);
```

when i click on delete button, not all been deleted.
`cmbJurusan` still exists.

Comment: you are inserting copies .... are you aware of that?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ That are all pointers, nothing is copied. In fact, `QObject`s cannot be copied

Comment: Hi Alcyone. If G.M.'s answer below solved your problem, you should accept it (by clicking the check mark under the vote count), rather than adding "Solved" to the title

Comment: @king_nak thanks you, i am new on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `for` loop isn't counting in quite the way you think it is.  You have...

```
for (int i = 0; i < hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count(); i++)
```

So you're incrementing `i` on each iteration.  But...

```
delete hBoxLayoutParent[index]->takeAt(0)->widget();
```

will remove an item from `hBoxLayoutParent[index]`.  So you're modifying the `QHBoxLayout` over whose items you're iterating -- each iteration increases `i` by one but also decreases the number of items in the layout by one.

Instead, try...

```
while (!hBoxLayoutParent[index]->isEmpty()) {
  delete hBoxLayoutParent[index]->takeAt(0)->widget();
  qDebug() << "Widget Number: " << hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count();
}
```

Note also that if this code is run within the context of the event loop then you might want to use [`QObject::deleteLater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) rather than `delete`.

Comment: thanks sir, i already realize it. but i did it in other way
`int j = hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count();
    for(int i = 1; i < j ; i++)
    {
        delete hBoxLayoutParent[index]->takeAt(0)->widget();
        qDebug() << "Widget Number: " << hBoxLayoutParent[index]->count();
    }
    hBoxLayoutParent.removeAt(index);`
this work same as your code right?